# Nginx: increase the number of allowed connections from the same browser

Tags: ajax, curl, browser, nginx, connection

I need your help on tuning a bit Nginx and my server.

I've got a website which is hosted on my server, and an API, also hosted on this server.

The website sends Ajax requests to the API. The problem is, once I've opened a page, which sends Ajax requests to the API, I cannot browse the website anymore using this browser because, I've reached the number of allowed connection for this browser on the website's server.

How can I change Nginx or the server configuration in order to increase the number of connections allowed per browser?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

*Server conf*

```
worker_processes 4;
worker_connections 1024;
multi_accept on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
```

*Server block*

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    mywebsite.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate    /path/to/pem;
        ssl_certificate_key    /path/to/key;

        # Set the server name
        server_name mywebsite.com;

        # add Strict-Transport-Security to prevent man in the middle attacks
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

        root /path/to/root/folder;
        index index.php;

        # Logs
        error_log /path/to/error.log;
        access_log /path/to/access.log;

        # strip app_test.php/ prefix if it is present
        rewrite ^/index\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

        location / {
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        }

        location @rewriteapp {
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server from upstream phpfcgi
        location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param  HTTPS on;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 43200;
                internal;
        }

        # Define error pages
        # Error pages are located in the app folder
        error_page 403 403.html;
        location = 403.html {
                root /path/to/error-pages;
                internal;
        }
        error_page 404 404.html;
        location = 404.html {
                root /path/to/error-pages;
                internal;
        }
        error_page 500 502 503 504 50x.html;
        location = 50x.html {
                root /path/to/error-pages;
                internal;
        }
}
```

Comment: I just added some of Nginx parameters in my initial message. Could you tell me if you're looking for a specific one?

Comment: You need to show server block config

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I just added it. Let me know if you need anything else.